Is it possible for grecaptcha.enterprise.execute to return empty or null values?
We have successfully integrated Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise into our site, and it functions perfectly when I fill out and submit the form. However, our logs reveal numerous error messages indicating that requests are missing the required non-empty reCAPTCHA token parameter.
Upon investigation, it appears that many of these errors are likely due to bot-like behavior, as we observe that the form is often submitted within just 1-2 seconds after the page is loaded. However, we also encounter cases where the issue does not seem to stem from automated scripts. In these instances, the form submission occurs after a reasonable period, suggesting that the issue might not be solely related to rapid submissions.
We have implemented Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise on our site by including the following script in the  section of our HTML:
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=SITE_KEY"></script>

On the frontend, we use a submitForm function to retrieve the reCAPTCHA token and submit the form data to our backend. The submitForm function is defined as follows:

function submitForm(form, url, siteKey) {
    // Display a loading spinner or similar indicator
    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
        const token = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute(siteKey, { action: 'submit' });
        
        // Perform additional processing for complex inputs
        const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        searchParams.append('g-recaptcha-response', token);
        
        // Submit the form data via a POST request
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: searchParams.toString(),
        })
        .then((response) => {
            // Handle the response from the server
            ...
        });

In this implementation, the fetch request is only executed after grecaptcha.enterprise.ready and await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute. Therefore, the token should be obtained before the POST request is made. However, if the token is empty, it could be due to Google returning an empty value or if the request is being sent manually, bypassing this JavaScript code.
My question is: Can grecaptcha.enterprise.execute return empty or null values?
If so, in which cases tokens can be empty? How should we correctly handle it? Is it safe to check the token in FE side before sending a POST request?
If not, is it something with our implementation? Why might it work in some cases but not in others?
I reviewed Google's documentation on reCAPTCHA but couldn't find relevant information about my question. Additionally, I checked the reCAPTCHA logs for incoming token requests, but it seems that only assessment requests are being logged.

After the script has loaded, the next step will be for the end-user to trigger an execution/generate a token. This happens in one of two situations:

For checkbox reCAPTCHA, when the user receives a green checkmark after clicking “I’m not a robot.”

For score-based reCAPTCHA, when the customer has configured grecaptcha.enterprise.execute to fire. This may be on button press, page load, or other action.


Token generation issues may manifest themselves in several ways:

Blank tokens (always)

Blank tokens (intermittent)

Invalid tokens (always)

Invalid tokens (intermittent)

Tokens that return BROWSER_ERROR on assessment


The grecaptcha.execute() call itself returns a promise that either resolves with a token or rejects with an error. To answer your questions:

No other errors other than the configuration/integration errors you cited are expected to be thrown and cause the promise to be rejected. Typically, these errors are expected to catch during setup and should not come up with a correct integration in production.

Given that the configuration is correct and that recaptcha is generating tokens correctly for some users, no other internal errors are expected to cause the promise to be rejected. Internal errors are passed as metadata via the token, and users are expected to continue to receive a resolved promise with a token in those cases. That said, from an adversarial standpoint, the execute call itself could always be overridden to simply throw an error and bypass returning the promise.

Execute calls have timeouts built in, so a token will always be returned disallowing the call from hanging.



Hi Sai,
Thank you for your response.
Just to clarify, does this mean that the reCAPTCHA token cannot be empty?

In front end, right after executing the grecaptcha.enterprise.execute, it will wait atmost 10s to wait for a token. If a token is not returned from Google then it would just send the empty token to backend. The backend rejects with an error. No assessment call made here.

Hi Sai,
Thanks for the insight! This could indeed be the case. Could you please provide a link to the documentation or any other sources where you found this information? I had assumed that any timeout would trigger an exception, which would then prevent the next request to the backend API.
